# Return Wildcard '%' value but display another value 'All' with ComboBox

Tags: javascript, combobox, wildcard, placeholder

I am using `document.getElementById` to pull a value from a comboBox to create a javascript query.  By default the wildcard `%` value is displayed in the combobox.  Here is my code for the comboBox:

```js
<select id="BDCategory"   
             dojotype="dijit/form/ComboBox"  
             style="width:200px;font-size:18px;"  
   value = '%'

             ></select>
```

What I want to do is instead of displaying `%` I want to display a descriptive phrase such as "All values."  However, I want my `document.getElementById` to pull the wildcard `%` value.  i.e. the user sees "All Values" but the Javascript sees the wildcard.
I have tried `FilteringSelect` in the following way but to no avail:

```html
   <select id="BDCategory"   
             dojotype="dijit/form/FilteringSelect"  
             style="width:200px;font-size:18px;"  
   data-dojo-props="
   name: 'category',
   value: '%',
   placeHolder: 'All Values'">

             ></select>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you include an `<option></option>` tag? Maybe I'm missing something... but try this:

HTML

```
<select id="BDCategory">
    <option value="%">All Values</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
var val = getElementById('BDCategory').value;
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I tried your code with the "option" but added the dijit/form/ComboBox and it still displays the % sign in the combobox.  Here is the code:<select id="BDCategory"   
             dojotype="dijit/form/ComboBox"
             style="width:200px;font-size:18px;"  
    <option value ="%">All Categories</option>
             ></select>

Comment: In order for my code to work in my application I need to use the dojotype combobox.  Is there a way to do this with the dojo combobox.

Comment: I apologize.  Please disregard the my above comment.  I did not put my > at the end of <select id="BDCategory".  Thank you for the help.  It does work.  However, to simplify the explanation I did not mention that I was populating my combo box with a ArcGis Javascript API querytask.  It is not populating the combobox now.  I may have to just hard code the values.  Thank your for the solution to my problem.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :-)